# Remove "Change background image" on Google homepage?

Tags: google-search

Google.com added a new feature called "change background image", I do not need this. Could I remove this link from my homepage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [style](http://userstyles.org/styles/34024) that someone built for exactly this reason. Of course, you need Stylish for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) or [FF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108/).

EDIT: chanchal1987 got it right. My solution is overly-complicated.

Answer (score 2):

See the "Remove Background Image" link on the bottom-left corner where you find "Change Background Image" link. This link is only visible after loading the image completely. So please wait until image is not fully loaded.